# Load native activity in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am looking to load a native activity (like Contacts or Text Message) into fragment of my activity. Is it possible, If so can anyone please paste the code or any link.

Thanks

Comment: Actually i Google this but wasn't sure.. so i just want to confirm the possibility.
please suggest any other way to extend the functionality of native applications. I don't wan't to start from scratch. Can i use the existing contact or text message application in my app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible

No. You cannot embed other applications' activities inside of your own.